# Unable to download from an authenticated webserver

Tags: browser, downloading, chrome-for-android

On my Galaxy S3 / ICS handset, and also I expect on my previous Galaxy S / Froyo I'm unable to save any links from my web server due to the fact that it requires a user authentication. I can browse the site happily in Chrome and the default browser, but when I go to save a link, whatever it is that does the downloading sends in an HTTP request with no user agent not authentication header set, so the download fails, with a 401 error being returned.

What gives, peeps?

Comment: Does it work with a different browser?

Comment: No, I just tried with Dolphin HD too. I don't think its the browser doing the download, it seems to hand off to some sort of generic subsystem. Works fine on my desktop though.

Comment: Hmm, strange...

Comment: Hmm... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1353

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firefox to get around this at the moment. The [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1353) has been going on since 2008.

Comment: I've been using Opera actually, so yeah as long as it's a different engine to Android default one it works.

Comment: The issue is not the browser, it's the download manager. The authentication details are not passed to the download manager by the browser. This isn't a problem in Opera or Firefox as they use their own download managers.