# PDF on a https server can not be downloaded with Chrome

Tags: downloading, https

I try to download a pdf on an https server (with an authenfication) but this is unsuccessful with Chrome or LG Browser.
This is ok with Firefox.
I found this answer/comment :
[Unable to download from an authenticated webserver](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25750/unable-to-download-from-an-authenticated-webserver#comment55798_41024).

Is there a solution for a non-power user ?

Comment: I don't understand the point of your question. You've found the existing question about this subject, and you know that the workaround is to use Firefox. What more do you want to know?

Comment: May be there is no answer, I'd like to know if there is something new or alternate solution.